# In non-blocking mode openssl allows to use any certificate on client side

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I changed BIO to a non-blocking mode with

`BIO_set_nbio(m_bio, 1)`

for `BIO_do_connect` to not hang (and using `BIO_should_retry` and `select` to retry to reconnect). It solved my problem with connection to the wrong listener now fails immediately instead of timing out in 2 hours.

But now I have a new problem - `SSL_get_verify_result` always returns `X509_V_OK`. Doesn't matter if it is expired cert or just not the same as server cert - validation always succeeds.

What I don't understand is how and why non-blocking mode changes validation for a cert. I confirmed that without switching to a non-blocking mode validation fails for if the client cert not the same.

I tried to set client cert with both `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` and `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file` and it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: non-blocking mode does not change validation. There must be an error  in your code somewhere but w/o actual code it is impossible to tell. Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that one take a closer look on what you are doing and find the problem.

Comment: Do you test things after the first application data exchanged? In some cases, just after the connection attempt you still do not have enough data from the TLS handshake to be able to do anything, and you will need to receive or send some application data before being able to test things for yourself (many libraries provide callbacks for these things so that they call your verification routines at the correct moment; some do all X.509 checks by themselves based on configuration given to them). Indeed a [mcve] will be needed and more details on your language, TLS library, etc.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thank you so much, that was exactly what I needed to solve my issue. Now I exchange some data with the server and my ctx has server cert after that which I can just compare to my cert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Patrick pointed out the issue I had was due to SSL context in non-blocking mode didn't have server cert so verification immediately after establishing a connection always succeeded. To fix the issue I added cert validation (if it is the same I expect to see) after first read-write data exchange.

```
SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, certFilePath, NULL);
BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, hostname);
BIO_set_nbio(bio, 1);
auto err = BIO_do_connect(bio);
// check err and BIO_should_retry to retry as needed

// Problem I had was here - the call always returns X509_V_OK
// in non-blocking mode regardless of what cert I use on 
// my (client) side.
// In IO blocking mode (without BIO_set_nbio call above) validation
// fails as expected for mismatching certs.
SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);

// Exchange some data with server with
// BIO_read/BIO_write

// And now we have server cert in ctx
auto clientCert = SSL_get_certificate(ssl);
auto serverCert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
auto certsAreTheSame = X509_cmp(clientCert, serverCert) == 0;
```